# raise error if not on correct matlab version

Tags: matlab, testing, version

I have a Matlab script, I would like to make sure it is run on any version but earlier than R2015a. Otherwise, the very same script should raise an exception.

The answer should work across OSes and for reasonably old Matlab versions (2006-2018).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `verLessThan` to check the version:

```
if verLessThan('matlab','8.5')
    % Run code normally
else
    error('Matlab version older than 8.5')
end
```

Matlab 8.5 is the version number of R2015a. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).